# Не перегружается оператор ">>"

Tags: c++

не получается перегрузить оператор ввода.
Выскакивает ошибка:

> бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа
>   "std::istream" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

В чем может быть проблема?

```
class Rational {
public:
    Rational() {

        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    Rational(int num, int denom) {
        int a = abs(num);
        int b = abs(denom);
        int nod;
        while (a != 0 && b != 0){
            if (a > b)
                a = a % b;
            else
                b = b % a;
        }
        nod = a + b;

        if ((denom < 0 && num>0) || (denom < 0 && num < 0)) {
            num = -num;
            denom = -denom;
        }
        numerator = num / nod;
        denominator = denom / nod;
    }

    int Numerator() const {                 
        return numerator;
    }
    int Denominator() const {               
        return denominator;
    }

private:
    int numerator, denominator;
};
```

Comment: Гм... `stream >> rat.Numerator()` - что возвращает `rat.Numerator()` - точно **ссылку**? А `rat.Denominator()`?

Comment: rat.Numerator() и rat.Denominator()   Возвращает просто значение переменной типа int

Comment: И как вы себе представляете чтение *в значение* - ну, наподобие `cin >> 5`?

Comment: Согласен, ошибка. Но тогда как можно перегрузить этот оператор для класса, у которого переменные типа 'private'

Comment: оператор сделать френдовым

Comment: Хотя почему не сделать методы set для установки Numerator и  Denominator?

Comment: @JaponDemon,  установить значения и читать с потока, совершенно разные функциональности.  Иногда нужно одна из двух, иногда и то и другое. В этом случаи просто нужно  оператор сделать другом класса

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Так и что ? Сделать сетторы и устанавливать в потоке.  Или сделать френдом ... собственно с Вами согласен " установить значения и читать с потока, совершенно разные функциональности."

Comment: Покажите ваш класс.

Comment: Причина выданной компилятором ошибки находится за пределами приведенного кода. Приводите весь относящийся к делу код, а не какие-то огрызки.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, возможно .., но автор вопроса пока не признается, что нужно.

Comment: @JaponDemon,  наши обсуждения  могут быть полезны нам самым или другим, и это  самое важное. Я например ошибся со словом селектор.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я начал изучать перегрузку операторов, и для класса нужно реализовать ввод данных через поток.  
Добавил свой класс в вопрос.

Comment: Ужос... теперь появился класс, но пропал оператор. Еще раз: приводите воспроизводимый пример. Из ваших огрызков ничего не ясно.

Answer (score 0):

Определите оператор как друг класса:

```
class Rational {
public:
    Rational() : numerator(0), denominator(1) {}

    //...
    friend istream& operator >>(istream& stream, Rational& r)
    {
        char c;
        stream >> numerator >> c >> denominator;
        return stream;
    }
private:
    int numerator, denominator;
};
```

Вы же так хотели кажется?..